# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse

Tags: ajax

When I try to parse a reponseText using  JSON.parse I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at
>   JSON.parse () at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange
>   (index.js:75)

Any time i run the code below.

**javascript/ajax code**

```
    function calculateMeasurements() {
        clearResult();
        clearErrors();

        var form = document.getElementById("measurement-form");
        var action = form.getAttribute("action");

        // gather form data
        var form_data = new FormData(form);
        for ([key, value] of form_data.entries()) {
            console.log(key + ': ' + value);
        }

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', action, true);
        // do not set content-type with FormData
        //xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                var result = xhr.responseText;
                var json = JSON.parse(result);
                if (json.hasOwnProperty('errors') && json.errors.length > 0) {
                    displayErrors(form, json.errors);
                } else {
                    postResult(json.volume);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.send(form_data);
    }

    var button = document.getElementById("ajax-submit");
    button.addEventListener("click", calculateMeasurements);

})();
```

**process.php**

```
<?php 
function is_ajax_request(){
    return $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] && $_SERVER["HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
}

  $length = isset($_POST['length']) ? (int) $_POST['length'] : '';
  $width = isset($_POST['width']) ? (int) $_POST['width'] : '';
  $height = isset($_POST['height']) ? (int) $_POST['height'] : '';

  $errors = [];

  if(empty($length)){$errors[] = "length";}

  if(empty($width)){$errors[] = "width";}

  if(empty($height)){$errors[] = "height";}

 if(!empty($errors)){
     $result_array = array('errors' => $errors);
     echo json.encode($result_array);
     exit;
 }

 $volume = $length * $width * $height;  
  if(is_ajax_request()) {
    echo json.encode(array('volume' => $volume));
  } else {
    exit;
  }

?>
```

I noticed this error anytime I use the JSON.parse on result variable gotten from the ajax response.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think their is anything wrong with your javascript code. please try using the php function properly. it should like this

```
echo json_encode(array('volume' => $volume)); 

echo json_encode($result_array);
```

AND NOT :

```
echo json.encode(array('volume' => $volume)); // json.encode as you have used in your code is wrong.

echo json.encode($result_array) // json.encode as you have used in your code is wrong.
```

it should work properly once this change is made

Comment: Thanks Onome Mine Adams. after making the corrections you sited. my code is working fine.